# Replacing responsive image with table which contains multiple images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image which is having img-responsive class attribute from bootstrap.

I want to replace that image with this table:
https://codepen.io/acosonic/pen/NwOqYR

A parent div, in which responsive image is, has the following css:

```
.mainhdr_ryt {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: -52px;
}
```

It's having width 50% meaning it scales, and I want that table to scale...

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle link so that it will be easy to solve

Comment: Does it have to be a table?

Comment: I will modify jsfiddle, hang on...

Comment: Modified, so I'm trying to replace girl in mainhdr_ryt div with table, given below.

Comment: Did you check the jQuery replaceWith() function ? You could have your table in display: none; and replace your image with your content whenever you want.

http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: But would it be responsive?